# Gold hijacking movie from the 1990's

Tags: identify-this-movie, action

I remember watching in 1998 this movie about a gold hijacking operation set in rural towns (maybe in Alaska, Canada or the Northwestern US or another place possibly).  Some terrorists who included one man with long reddish hair and a short beard (he was always hitting people hard) were carrying stolen gold (if I remember correctly) from place to place and the other main characters included a married couple (I remember the man's first name was Mel, but other than that have no memories of any character's names) on vacation in an RV.  When they obtain the gold he places it in the RV's gas tank for safety transport (there was another gas tank on the other side of the vehicle so this apparently would not have interfered with it's operation).  The terrorists however manage to find them and at the conclusion (spoiler obviously!) all the main characters are dead and the RV gets pulled into a junkyard with the gold still in the gas tank.  The movie ends there and the gold likely got disposed of.  Now searching for this movie on amazon.com two days ago I thought I remembered the name but I was incorrect.  From what I've said can anyone identify this movie for me?  It would have been made in either 1998 or at some point before that.

Answer (score 3):

OK, this seems more like it. In [The Killing Grounds](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0185400/combined) from 1998, the bad guys steal a load of gold when their plane crashes. It's found by a married couple out for a camping trip; the husband (Charles Rocket) is called Mel. The couple hides the gold in their vehicle's spare gas tank; the bad guys go after them and one of them has long red hair, a short beard and a violent temper. In the end, all the main characters die and the vehicle is towed to a junkyard with the stolen gold still inside. It also stars Anthony Michael Hall. Here's the trailer:

Comment: That's IT!!  Thanks you so much for your help.  I thought it was called On Dangerous Grounds or something along those lines.  I don't know how you managed to find it but you rock!

Comment: @Kenneth Glad to help. :) Don't forget to click on the check mark to close the question.

Answer (score 1):

Possibly [Pressure Point](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0268548/combined) (AKA Backroad Justice). The villain, who has long red hair and a short beard, robs a bank then takes over an RV of a family on vacation, but the husband's name is Jed and not Mel, it's cash and not gold and the film is from 2001. From an online synopsis:

> Jed Griffin (Michael Madsen) is traveling through Vermont in a motor home with his wife and family when they happen upon Rudy Wicker (Jeff Wincott). Wicker is a desperate criminal whose attempt to rob a bank left several customers dead, including the wife of the town sheriff; now he's on the run from the police, and when Rudy sees Jed and his RV, he steals the vehicle with Jed's family still inside, and shoots Jed to keep him out of the way. Jed was not killed by Rudy's bullet, just wounded, but now the police believe he's the man they're looking for, so Jed has to find a way to prove his innocence while tracking down his camper to save his family from Rudy.

Here's the trailer:

Comment: Thank you for the response but unfortunately this is not the same one as it's from 2001 and the movie I watched was made no later than 1998.  Also there's the differences you pointed out such as the characters having different names and gold not being involved.  Also in the movie I was referring to there were no children.  In any case this movie has many similarities and looks intriguing from the same perspective.  Again thank you for replying!

Comment: @Kenneth Thanks for the comment. It helped and I think I found it for *real* this time - another answer to follow.